# Rx Subject can't use observeOn() operator

Tags: android, rx-java2

I've declared:

```
Subject<String> mBehaviorSubject = BehaviorSubject.createDefault("default").toSerialized();
```

Seems to work fine. But I now want to add `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()`. This is rejected because Android Studio wants to see a `Subject` and is finding an `Observable`. But according to the documentation, `Subject` inherits the `observeOn()` method from the `Observable` class. How do I make this work?

P.S. Assuming I can do this, is there any preferred order of the operators `observeOn()` and `toSerialized()`?

Update: here is the actual complete code I'm trying to use:

```
Subject<String> stringPublisher; 
...
stringPublisher = BehaviorSubject.createDefault("default").toSerialized().observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

Android Studio says "incompatible types: required: io.reactivex.subjects.Subject; found: io.reactivex.Observable"

Comment: Can you post the code you're trying to use?

Comment: Applying `observeOn` should work. Maybe you have a syntax error in your code.

Comment: It’s what I said: adding `observeOn` to the declaration

Comment: I’ll post complete code as soon as I get back to computer

Comment: BTW if I insert `observeOn()` in the call, like this, it compiles OK: `stringPublisher.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is rejected because Android Studio wants to see a `Subject` and is finding an `Observable`. But according to the documentation, `Subject` inherits the `observeOn()` method from the `Observable` class.

You are correct that `Subject` inherits this method, but that doesn't change the return type of the `observeOn` method; it still returns an `Observable<T>`. Because you're trying to do assignment, this will break.

Let's go through each call...

```
Subject<String> subject = BehaviorSubject.createDefault("default");
```

This is fine; `createDefault()` returns a `BehaviorSubject<T>`, which is a subclass of `Subject<T>`, so there's no problem assigning its value to our `subject` variable.

```
Subject<String> subject = BehaviorSubject.createDefault("default").toSerialized();
```

This is also fine; `toSerialized()` returns a `Subject<T>`, so our assignment still works. Note, though, that this is still "less specific" than `BehaviorSubject<T>`, so if our variable declaration were instead `BehaviorSubject<String> subject`, this would already break.

```
Subject<String> subject = BehaviorSubject.createDefault("default")
                                         .toSerialized()
                                         .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

Here we finally break. `observeOn()` returns an `Observable<T>`, and while a `Subject` "is an" `Observable`, we still cannot make the assignment anymore because we have an object of the wrong type. This is similar to trying to assign an `Object` to a `String` variable.

So, you either have to change your declaration to `Observable<String> subject` (so that you can perform the assignment), or you have to break your code up into an assignment and a statement:

```
Subject<String> subject = BehaviorSubject.createDefault("default").toSerialized();
Observable<String> observable = subject.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

Comment: Thanks for the walk-through. I don't want to declare it as an `Observable` because then I won't be able to use it as a `Subject` (call its `onNext()` method to emit an item), right? So either I use your second alternative or just insert `observeOn` before each `subscribe`? (was hoping to avoid this as I often forget to do it, which leads to confusing errors).